# What is the instance name of the box I'm logged into?

Tags: oracle, instance

I'm at the linux prompt of a computer running Oracle 11.

Without connecting to the database, how can I determine what is the instance name of the Oracle server running on this box?

Comment: What do you want to see if there is more than one instance? In most Linux distributions you can check the instances by looking at `/etc/oratab`

Comment: I'm flexible on what I want to see.  It looks like oratab and grep pmon are both good.  Basically I'm logging on to some tests boxes that have been set up and deducing a connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the DB is running, you can look for the pmon process:

```
ps auxww | grep pmon | grep -v grep
```

You'll see one `pmon` process for each database that is up. For example `ora_pmon_YOURDB`, where `YOURDB` is the instance name.

You can also ask the listener which services it is serving connections for, with:

```
lsnrctl status
```

Answer (score 0):

(Channeling for a_horse_with_no_name, who left a good answer in a comment.)

In most Linux distributions you can check the instances by looking at `/etc/oratab`.

```
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
orcl:/data/oracle/software:N
```

Answer (score -2):

if you've installed Oracle with the installer, you can try with this:

> echo $ORACLE_SID

Comment: All that tells you is the value of the `$ORACLE_SID` environment variable in the current shell. It tells you nothing about running services.